# Send recorded audio from browser to django server and save as .wav

Tags: javascript, python, django, audio

I'm trying to build a web app that would record the audio from browser and send the recorded audio to django API after every 3 seconds for analysis(emotion recognition from voice). I'm using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) for recording audio. **But only noise is saved in the wave file.**

I'm trying to send the recorded audio(as a blob) to the django api. And then on receiving it at backend, I save it as a wav file.

I'm sending the recorded audio like this:

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(stream => {audio_handler(stream)});
    var audio_chunks = [];

    audio_handler = function(stream){
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType : 'audio/webm', codecs : "opus"});
        rec.ondataavailable = function(e){
            audio_chunks.push(e.data);
        }
    }

    //on rec.stop() 
    var blob = new Blob(audio_chunks, {'type':'audio/wav; codecs=opus'});
    console.log(blob);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/er/", true);
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', blob, 'audio_blob');
    xhttp.send(data);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);     
         }
    };
```

Saving on django backend as:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
import wave

def get_emotion(request):
    print(request.FILES.get('data'))
    audio_data = request.FILES.get('data')
    print(type(audio_data)) 
    print(audio_data.size)
    audio = wave.open('test.wav', 'wb')
    audio.setnchannels(1)
    audio.setnframes(1)
    audio.setsampwidth(1)
    audio.setframerate(16000)
    blob = audio_data.read()
    audio.writeframes(blob) #on playing 'test.wav' only noise can be heard
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Currently the audio file saved just has some noise in it, whereas I expect the wave audio file saved to have same content as the audio spoken while recording.

**Please suggest, if there is any other way to do the same thing(record an audio from browser and send it to a django api, to save it as an audio file there).**

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask. Thank you!

Comment: So what's the issue? You get an error? Something else? If you only explain what you want but not what is happening, then we can only guess what's the problem.

Comment: @dirkgroten No there is no error. The file gets saved, but the thing is that the wave file only contains noise, and not the audio which was spoken while recording.

Comment: So maybe add that to your question. You didn't say that.

Answer (score 0):

Wav file format don't support Opus codec.

For Opus codec you need to use webm file format.

So you need to change this

new Blob(audio_chunks, {'type':'audio/wav; codecs=opus'});

to

new Blob(audio_chunks, {'type':'audio/webm; codecs=opus'});

or

new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM' }); //if it is supported.

Make sure the file that you are saving the blob is also of the same file format as send.

Comment: Tried for both wav(with ms_pcm codec) and webm format. But the problem is still the same. It is still just noise.

Comment: Please let me know if you are able to record the file locally ( same pc where you are running the mediarecorder and play it ( wav/pcm, webm/opus)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I advise you to set the original arguments to audio while saving, instead of hard-coding random figures:

```
        obj = wave.open(audio_data, 'r')
        audio = wave.open('/../test.wav', 'wb')
        audio.setnchannels(obj.getnchannels())
        audio.setnframes(obj.getnframes())
        audio.setsampwidth(obj.getsampwidth())
        audio.setframerate(obj.getframerate())
        blob = audio_data.read()
        audio.writeframes(blob)
```

This would set the actual channel, frames, width etc to the audio you are writing without any introduction of noise in you .wav file . Make sure you are using `Django==1.8.19` at least

Answer (score 0):

If you get only noise in frontend in audio when its recorded, then go to microphone settings and set from default-microphone(high)[number 1 usually] to microphone(high)[number 4 usually]. this will remove the noise and you will get clear voice(frontend).